# Bug in tensorflow tuttorial about quantization

Tags: c++, tensorflow

This post follow my another post about op not registered: : 
[NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'Dequantize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595600/notfounderror-op-type-not-registered-dequantize)

And now when I try load manually as in this post: 
[Install Tensorflow with Quantization Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428718/install-tensorflow-with-quantization-support)

with:

```
qops = tf.load_op_library('/home/artem/projects/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/_quantized_ops.so')
qkernelops = tf.load_op_library('/home/artem/projects/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/kernels/_quantized_kernels.so')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-799f99708cda> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 qops = tf.load_op_library('/home/artem/projects/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/_quantized_ops.so')
      3 qkernelops = tf.load_op_library('/home/artem/projects/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/kernels/_quantized_kernels.so')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.pyc in load_op_library(library_filename)
     69           return _OP_LIBRARY_MAP[library_filename]
     70       # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 71       raise errors._make_specific_exception(None, None, error_msg, error_code)
     72       # pylint: enable=protected-access
     73   finally:

NotFoundError: /home/artem/projects/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/_quantized_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8internal21CheckOpMessageBuilder9NewStringB5cxx11Ev
```

It is look like that it is a problem with C++ compiler and probably I should add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` as in this post: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/1584

but actually I did `bazel-build` and I don't know how manage it.

Anybody can help me? Test example from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/quantization/index.html also don't work. 
It will be great if someone would write detailed manual about quantization generally.

Comment: sounds like a good subject for github issue, mentioning @petewarden

Comment: Thank you for advice. 
I create it here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow 0.10 is released! I solved this problem after updating! 
Add those code in your script:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.quantization import load_quantized_ops_so
from tensorflow.contrib.quantization.kernels import load_quantized_kernels_so
```

and

```
load_quantized_ops_so.Load()
load_quantized_kernels_so.Load()
```

Thanks the TF teams!